# localStorage not set

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Could anybody perhaps suggest why the following code would not store the stylsheet choice.

SETTINGS.PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeStyle(title) {
var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
for (var i = lnks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
if (lnks[i].getAttribute('rel').indexOf('style')> -1 && lnks[i].getAttribute('title')) {
lnks[i].disabled = true;
if (lnks[i].getAttribute('title') == title) lnks[i].disabled = false;
}}}
function getActiveStyleSheet() {
var i, a;
 for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")); i++) {
  if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
  && a.getAttribute("title")
  && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
} 
localStorage.setItem('activeStylesheet', getActiveStyleSheet())
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Intapp.Com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dwcss.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet"  type="text/css"  title="girly" href="style1.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="default" href="dwcss.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet"  type="text/css"  title="neutral" href="style2.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320.1, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0 minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<h1> User Settings </h1>
</div>
<div id="box2">
To change to this style click here
<button onclick="changeStyle('girly')">Girly</button>
<button onclick="changeStyle('default')">Default</button>
<button onclick="changeStyle('neutral')">Neutral</button>  
</div> 
<div class="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is where i am trying to retrieve the local storage value when i test in the browser the default stylsheet is activated on index.php, i can't see what i'm doing wrong if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

INDEX.PHP

```
<html>
<head> 
<script>
window.onload=setstyle()
{
localStorage.getItem('activeStylesheet')
}
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="appsplash.png">
<title>Intapp.Com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dwcss.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="default" href="dwcss.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet"  type="text/css"  title="neutral" href="style2.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320.1, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0 minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="applogo.png"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
</head>
```

Comment: Where is `setstyle` defined?

Comment: i thought the stuff in the curly braces composed the function

Comment: Only if the `function` keyword is used (e.g. `window.onload = function() { ... }` or `window.onload = function setstyle() { ... }`).

Comment: i changed the code to your first example, (function(){}) and it still doesnt work.  thanks for your input max, im really new to this as you can tell and i appreciate your explanations :)

Comment: I've updated my original answer to indicate what should be done on index.php.

Comment: you are amazing!! it's working (kind of!!) it's changing the stylsheet on the index page but not to the one that was set in settings, but it is changing, i'll see if i can  work out from the code why it's setting the wrong one :)

Comment: it's changing the stylsheet to one in the alternate stylsheet lists but is not changing it back when i click back on the defualt setting

Comment: I made a typo in the window.onload function.  See if the new version works.

Comment: i actually love you! thankyou so so much, i've been googling local storage for weeks trying to sort this out.  many many thanks. :)

Comment: I don't think the issue here is lack of knowledge of localStorage (you were using it correctly); you probably should improve your JavaScript fundamentals through e.g. a JavaScript tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getActiveStylesheet`, your for loop is setting `a` to `document.getElementsByTagName("link")` each iteration, while you should be iterating through it:

```
function getActiveStyleSheet() {
  var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
  for (var i = lnks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (lnks[i].getAttribute('rel').indexOf('style')> -1 && lnks[i].getAttribute('title') && !lnks[i].disabled) {
      return lnks[i].getAttribute("title");
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Also, instead of setting activeStylesheet when the page loads, you should set it every time the style is changed, i.e. at the end of changeStyle:

```
function changeStyle(title) {
  var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
  for (var i = lnks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (lnks[i].getAttribute('rel').indexOf('style')> -1 && lnks[i].getAttribute('title')) {
      lnks[i].disabled = true;
      if (lnks[i].getAttribute('title') == title) lnks[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }
  localStorage.setItem('activeStylesheet', getActiveStyleSheet())
}
```

On index.php, there should be code to actually set the style, such as:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var
    lnks = document.getElementsByTagName('link'),
    activeStylesheet = localStorage.getItem('activeStylesheet');
  for (var i = lnks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (lnks[i].getAttribute('rel').indexOf('style') > -1 && lnks[i].getAttribute('title'))
      lnks[i].disabled = lnks[i].getAttribute('title') != activeStylesheet;
};
```

Of course, you should try to factor out the duplicate code shared between these three code blocks at some point.

PS: In general, if you indent your code, it'll be far easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you transitively copied this code from http://alistapart.com/article/alternate.  If so, you may be able to just use http://d.alistapart.com/alternate/styleswitcher.js, with the following changes:

- Replace calls to `readCookie(name)` with calls to `localStorage.getItem(name)`
- Replace calls to `createCookie(name, value, days)` with calls to `localStorage.setItem(name, value)`